# How to render react-icons on native?

Tags: reactjs

I want to render icons on native from the react-icons package, but the icon is not showing. Currently my code is looking like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import * as MaterialDesign from 'react-icons/md';

const StyledTab = styled.View`
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
`;

const Tab = ({ icon, type, text, color }) => {
 let mdIcon = null;

 if (icon) {
  mdIcon = React.createElement(Text, [], [MaterialDesign[icon]]);
 }
 return (
  <StyledTab icon={icon} type={type} text={text} color={color}>
   {mdIcon}
   <Text>{text}</Text>
  </StyledTab>
 );
};

Tab.propTypes = {
 /** Text of tab */
 text: PropTypes.string,
 /** Text of tab */
 type: PropTypes.oneOf(['default', 'inline', 'icons']),

 color: PropTypes.string,

 icon: PropTypes.string
};

Tab.defaultProps = {
  text: null,
  type: 'default',
  color: '#000',
  icon: null
};

/**
 * @component
*/
export default Tab;
```

So the part:

```
const Tab = ({ icon, type, text, color }) => {
 let mdIcon = null;

 if (icon) {
  mdIcon = React.createElement(Text, [], [MaterialDesign[icon]]);
 }
 return (
  <StyledTab icon={icon} type={type} text={text} color={color}>
   {mdIcon}
   <Text>{text}</Text>
  </StyledTab>
 );
};
```

is not rendering the icon and not showing anything. Can someone help me with this? Do i need a different way to render this icon on native?